# Image not exporting correctly in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to export a column chart as a JPEG but it does not export correctly.

I think the dimensions of the image need to be changed. Also, there is some unwanted text next to the first column(Manhattan). That too seems like an error.

Here is the exported image:
[image: Exported Image]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Percentage 311 calls pertaining to rats/mice in NYC within 1 block from restaurant</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
${demo.css}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Percentage 311 calls pertaining to rats/mice in NYC within 1 block from restaurant'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: NYC Open DataSet'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            labels: {
                rotation: 0,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px'
                }
            }
        },
        data: {
            csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Percentage'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: 'Percentage: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                grouping: false,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    rotation: -90,
                    align: 'right',
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    format: '{point.y:.2f}', // one decimal
                    y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '13px',
                    }
                }   
            }        
        }
    });
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="../../js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/themes/dark-unica.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 300px; max-width: 900px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<pre id="csv" style="display:none">
BOROUGH
Manhattan,50.74
Queens,,25.31
Bronx,,,49.68
Brooklyn,,,,33.28
Staten Island,,,,,39.45
</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gvwcdjp/10/)

Comment: can you provide a live demo in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: JSFiddle in the main post with theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the theme you can use something like this:

```
Highcharts.theme = {
    colors: ["#2b908f", "#90ee7e", "#f45b5b", "#7798BF", ...],

    chart: {
              backgroundColor: {...}
              ...
    },

    style: {

              fontFamily: "sans-serif",

    },

    .....
};

// Apply the theme
Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);
```

As for the exporting function you can use **`exporting.chartOptions`** to set the options you want to be exported, like width and height of the chart:

```
exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
        chart: {
            width: 300,
            height: 300
        }
    }
}
```

Or the font size of the title for that matter. The unwanted text appears when you use **`plotOptions.column.dataLabels.rotation`**. I don't know the reason and I think it may be a bug in Highcharts.

Here's a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3gvwcdjp/9/).

Comment: @SebastianBochan possible bug?

Comment: @PawełFus possible bug?

Comment: I can now export it in correct dimensions but the unwanted text still remains. It might be a bug as you suggested.

Comment: @Viraj For now don't use the rotation as it will be correctly exported that way.

Comment: Indeed, it's a bug, caused by `textShadow` option. Use different style, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/3gvwcdjp/11/ or disable shadow: http://jsfiddle.net/3gvwcdjp/12/ Reopened [issue #3649](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3649) - thanks!

Comment: Using a different style works for me. Thanks @PawelFus.